# What could cause these slight waves on the print?

Tags: marlin, print-quality

The model of the test part is perfectly smooth and exported/sliced in very high resolution, yet there are slight waves on both axis. These waves are not visible in simulation. Converting to arcs via Arc-Welder does not change anything. No stuttering due to the high resolution of G-code (as it's a 32-bit board).

As there are no stops, and speed is uniform - I expect no ringing. What could be the cause?

Ghost4 printer, SKR-PRO board with Marlin bugfix-2.0.x.

[image: Example print]

Comment: What are your printer's esteps per mm?

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE X160.00 Y160.00 Z400.00 E1660.00

Comment: Ok, 1660 is high enough that extrusion shouldn't be quantized enough to cause this.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an issue which repeats EXACTLY layer after layer. I already explained how to solve it in https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/18835/2338 but I answer it again, limiting to this case.

Waves which are exactly aligned vertically, and everywhere, not only after changes of direction, like in

[image]

are NOT ringing or "ghosting", they are rather caused by

- too tight belt (almost always!)
- poor quality belt
- poor bearings or idlers (not common)

I also had the issue and it was the belt, too tight. Loosen it, since it can be much looser than you think!

Check [How to fix evenly spaced vertical print pattern](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/8020/how-to-fix-evenly-spaced-vertical-print-pattern) to get more information.

Comment: From my reading it also looks like it might be stepper motor non-uniform steps / resonances.

Comment: @BarsMonster it's highly unlikely, if you try to calculate how much such non-uniformities can impact a print. Like 1/8 of a step (12% is already big, it is in fact less than that) would translate in 25 microns for a 20T pulley, and would repeat with 40 mm periodicity. If it repeats with about 2 mm period, it's likely belt related. Have you tried loosening the belt?